# Controlling raspberry gpio using a config file

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I would like to control the GPIO pins of my raspberry pi using a config file, what i mean by this is using the following file:

```
Pin 1 : 1
Pin 2 : 0
Pin 3 : 1
...
```

And then i would have a python script that would read from the file and have something like(using wiringPi library):

```
variable= read from the config file in line x 
gpio -g write 14(BCM pin number that corresponds to line x in the config file),variable

*Text representation of the code, not real code, obviously, so please don't tell me 
 the syntax is wrong or something like that...
```

This file will be sent then by scp to a remote server where it must be parsed to show in an html page.

How could i achieve this? What's the best approach? grep and cat the file? could someone give me an example of how you would do this?

Comment: What is exactly your question ? 
I understand that you want to share a configuration file between a python script that will actually set the GPIO values, and an application that will display the content of the script.
Are you looking for advice regarding the configuration-file format ?

Comment: basically the help i want is when changing the file, what can i use to read the line of the file and change it to the value i want? Also, if i want to change from the server instead of the raspberry, what can i use? can i edit the file using php?

Answer (score 1):

Use python dictionary in config file and import it in main script and access it.

```
#config.py
pins = {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1}
```

and in your main script:

```
#main.py
import config
...
gpio.write(config.pins[pin_num], 'sample write')
```

Note that there is no method called `gpio.write`, I just made it up for illustration.

If you keep changing the pins config, then it's better to save the config in a json file like:

```
#config.json
{
    "1": 1,
    "2": 0,
    "3": 1
}
```

Now just change the main script like:

```
#main.py
import json
config_file = 'config.json'
with open(config_file) as f:
    pins = json.loads(f.read())
...
gpio.write(config.pins[pin_num], 'sample write')
...
...
# if you want change pins, just change values in pins dictionary
pins['1'] = 0
# now write it to json file
with open(config_file) as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(pins))
```

If changes to pins is frequent then write a method which can do that for you, makes the code better.

Comment: so if i do it like this, how can i change the config file to change the status of the GPIO?

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: my goal is not to just have the config file set once and never change it, my goal is to change the config file as needed in order to change the status of the gpio pins, this way i can connect to the webserver by ftp and send the file so the html/php/javascript/whatever can parse the data and present it in the webpage showing the status of the GPIO pins

Comment: for that you better store that data in json file, since editing is simple. Give me a minute, I will update the answer.

Comment: edited, check and let me know if that solved your problem. And accept my answer if it did. :)